# aria-label="toggle" for button is reported as INVALID in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, wcag

I am trying to use `aria-label` attribute with a button. But whenever I am adding this attribute PhpStorm is reporting it as **INVALID**. But other `aria` attributes are already present with the same button and not being reported.

```
<button class="tablet-only" aria-label="Toggle primary menu" aria-controls="primary-menu" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button>
```

Is this a PhpStorm related issue and I can ignore and continue?
Any suggestion would be helpful.

Screenshot

[image]

Comment: looks like you searched for something and changed something later. after the change the search result isn't valid anymore.

Comment: @SebastianBrosch +1 Thanks for your quick reply! I though it is coming because of the attribute I am adding. You pinned it. :)